# Python interpreter for Android

Tags: python, android, sl4a, p4a

I am a intermediate python developer .I want to know how pydroid is able to run python on Android, I mean how pydroid's python interpreter works and is there a way we can create such interpreter and bind it with our gui program so that it runs on that interpreter same as pydroid run our programs. Also I know about kivy but I want to know that if it's possible.

Comment: Hi Kunal, 

Stackoverflow isn't usually a place for software recommendations, try [Software Recommendations Stackexchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Back to your question: why do you want to create an interpreter? When your users use your software, do you want them to use it via a command line that appears on the device? (Termux) Or do you want it so that you open an app and it runs your python code, and presents the output in a GUI? Kivy already seems like a good option.

Comment: Actually like a pwa where we use webview to run web technologies that behave like an app
I want to know is something similar is possible. I know there are much better option available for app development. But just to make joy of programming also kivy is not very modern

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not able to explain my point I am new in asking questions in stackoverflow

Comment: the question needs code. it appears to be a open ended discussion.